# Upgrade of JAVA JRE - On System at OS Level

Tags: java, upgrade, compatibility

We want to upgrade JAVA installed on the machine at OS level and we have very few applications installed majorly three. Each of them have their own JAVA JRE.

Question: Does upgrading this system JAVA will have an impact on these applications as each of them use their own JRE and their versions are different when compared with the central JAVA installed on the machine.

Answer (score 0):

If the applications each have (and use!!) an embedded JRE installation, then upgrading the system-level JRE won't affect them.

On the other hand ... if none of the applications you have installed make use the system-level JRE, it is unclear why you need it to be installed in the first place.